# XNA - GraphicsDevice Initialization confusion

Tags: c#, initialization, xna

So it's well known that you're supposed to call game's base.Initialize() before using the game object's GraphicsDevice right? That's what I gathered from reading a lot of tutorials online.

Apparently that's not where game's GraphicDevice is created because I'm able to use it before base.Initalize() like this...

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

    // I use the game's GraphicsDevice in here to create a 
    // SpriteBatch, BasicEffect, ect. and it's VALID
    Engine.Initialize();

    base.Initialize();
}
```

What magic is happening in **Game.Run()** that would initialize the GraphicDevice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XNA documentation specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.initialize.aspx) that Initialize is *"Called after the Game and GraphicsDevice are created, but before LoadContent."*  The tutorials that state otherwise are incorrect.

Game.Run creates a graphics device and then calls Initialize.

```
this.graphicsDeviceManager = this.Services.GetService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceManager)) as IGraphicsDeviceManager;
if (this.graphicsDeviceManager != null)
{
    this.graphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice();
}
this.Initialize();
```

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to investigate the internal code of the XNA assemblies yourself.